# Query Parse Pointer for PFObject Display on UILabel in different Class - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, parse-platform, uilabel

I have painted myself into a corner and I need some help please!

Parse Class "Order" holds the data created when a User adds a Product to their Bag, including a PFObject Pointer for "jarName" which is pointing to the Parse Class "Jar" with String "jarName".

I need to display string "jarName" in a UILabel on a PFTableViewCell "OrderItemTableViewCell" sitting on a UITableViewController "BagTableViewController".  But...and this is the corner I painted myself into..."OrderItemTableViewCell" uses the model "OrderItem", but "jarName" is not on the OrderItem model (or Parse Class), it is on the Order model and Parse Class "Order".

[image: Parse Class Order holding Pointer jarName]

jarName is a pointer to the Parse Class "Jar" for the string "jarName".

[image: Parse Class Jar holding String jarName]

The PFObjet jarName is created on the UITableViewController

```
@interface ProductDetailViewController ()

{
    PFObject* _selectedJar;
}

"ProductDetailViewController" when a user selects the Product they want to purchase, select the jarName associated with that Product and then adds them to their bag using a UIButton. The view then pops to BagTableViewController.

    //  ProductDetailViewController.m    
    - (void)didSelectAddToBagButton:(UIButton *)addToBagButton {
            if (![User currentUser]) {
                [self showWarning];
            } else {
                if (self.order) {
                    if ([self.order.items count] > 0) {
                        if ([self containsProduct:self.order.items target:self.product] > -1) {
                            int index = [self containsProduct:self.order.items target:self.product];
                            NSMutableArray *eItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.order.items];
                            OrderItem *foundItem = eItems[index];
                            [foundItem setQuantity:foundItem.quantity+1];
                            [eItems replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:foundItem];
                            self.order.items = [eItems copy];
                        } else {
                            [self.order addSingleProduct:self.product];
                        }
                    } else {
                        [self.order addSingleProduct:self.product];
                    }
                } else {
                    self.order = [Order object];
                    [self.order setCustomer:[User currentUser]];
                    [self.order setOrderStatus:ORDER_NOT_MADE];
                    [self.order addSingleProduct:self.product];
                    [self.order setJarName:_selectedJar];

                }
            }
```

BagTableViewController holds the view OrderItemTableViewCell which is populated by the data from the OrderItem model associated to the Parse Class OrderItem.

```
//  BagTableViewController.m

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 130;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.order.items count];
}

- (OrderItemTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    OrderItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BagItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (self.order) [cell configureItem:self.order.items[indexPath.row] tag:indexPath.row];
    else [cell configureItem:nil tag:100+indexPath.row];
        return cell;
}
```

So, here is the rub...

I need to populate a UILabel inside the OrderItemTableViewCell with data from the Parse Class Order while 4 other labels are being populated by data from the Parse Class OrderItem.

```
//  OrderItemTableViewCell.m

@interface OrderItemTableViewCell()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *jarNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *unitPriceLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *quantityLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIStepper *quantityStepper;
@end

@implementation OrderItemTableViewCell

    -(void)configureItem:(OrderItem *)item tag:(long)tag{
        if (item) {

            self.nameLabel.text = item.product.name;
            self.unitPriceLabel.text = [item.product friendlyPrice];
            self.quantityLabel.text = [item friendlyQuantity];
            self.quantityStepper.hidden = NO;
            self.quantityStepper.value = item.quantity;
            self.quantityStepper.stepValue = 1;
            self.quantityStepper.tag = tag + 100;
        } else {
            self.nameLabel.text = @"";
            self.unitPriceLabel.text = @"";
            self.quantityLabel.text = @"";
            self.quantityStepper.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
@end
```

So basically, I have a Pointer in a different class that I need to retrieve and display the String as a UILabel.

(1) How do I query the Pointer "jarName" from the Parse Class Order and have it return the String "jarName" from the Parse Class "Jar"?

(2) How do I display that String on the UILabel in the OrderItemTableViewCell (which is populated by the OrderItem model...which does not contain the string or pointer)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly ...
You call FetchIfNeeded to populate pointer objects nested inside a PFObject. This works, I use it all time to populate pointers, and the objects and values inside pointers of pointers of pointers of ... etc. etc. You can nest as many pointers as you'd like, just call this this method on the pointer object, wait for completion, and then set the object in the place where the pointer is.

Example:

```
PFObject * orderObjectFromOrderClass = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Order"];
[[orderObjectFromOrderClass objectForKey:@"jarName"] fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        [orderObjectFromOrderClass setObject:object forKey:@"jarName"];
    }
}];

NSString * jarName = [[orderObjectFromOrderClass objectForKey:@"jarName"] valueForKey:@"jarName"];
```

Key Note:

If you fail to fetch the pointers using FetchIfNeeded then an error will be thrown that you need to call "FetchIfNeeded" on that pointer object FIRST because the value doesn't exist. So, if you have a class with pointers and YOU'VE NOT QUERIED those pointers using PFQuery and the "includeKey" (with or without dot notation depending on what your needs are) then the PFObject that you're calling to WILL NOT have the data for those pointer objects. YOU MUST call FetchIfNeeded if you've not yet fleshed out those pointer values.

Update, define the NSString inside like so to make sure you have a value for the NSString

```
PFObject * orderObjectFromOrderClass = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Order"];
    [[orderObjectFromOrderClass objectForKey:@"jarName"] fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            [orderObjectFromOrderClass setObject:object forKey:@"jarName"];
            NSString * jarName = [[orderObjectFromOrderClass objectForKey:@"jarName"] valueForKey:@"jarName"];
            // set your cell lable text here to make sure there's a value for "jarName" from the pointer
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Great! I am going to try it right now. Thank you for responding! I am assuming you call the PFObject inside the Cell and then push it to the UILabel?

Comment: Yep, you can do that, either way, just make sure you call to that function FIRST, and also, I would set the UILabel text ONLY after that block executes, so create the label or whatever, add it to the subview or whatever, and then SET the text inside that fetch block to make sure that there's a value for that text in the object coming from the backend

Comment: Thanks! I am still learning and once the data has to go deep like this...I struggle

Comment: Oh, no worries, it gets super easy after you understand this simple construction. After you do this a few times it will "click" and you'll kick yourself in the ass that it was so easy.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to set it on the OrderItemTableViewCell. If you look at my code from earlier, I created -(void) retrieveJarName and put your code inside it.  Then I called [self retrieveJarName] inside -(void) configureItem, but that didn't work.

Comment: yeah, go step by step, first set up the Fetch methods, then Log the outPut of the the Order class object, "object" to see if it shows anything

Comment: I wish I understood what that meant. Haha! I have taught myself how to do all of this and I struggle to understand the language.  So I don't know what you mean by "set up the Fetch methods" or log the output.  I suck! I will keep trying until I get it right :)

Comment: that's okay, I'll show you more in a bit, but this is the logging i mean NSLog(@"log object %@", object);

Comment: I tried setting it up a bunch of different ways, I even tried moving the fetch to a diff view controller just to see if I could log the correct jarName, but I couldn't get it to work. Not sure what I am missing.